# How can i optimize/speed up the response time of Ajax

Tags: ajax, performance, optimization, response

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert_comment(id)
{
    var comment_des         = $("#comment_text_"+id).val();

    var fk_post_id          = $("#fk_post_id_"+id).val();
    var post_user_id        = $("#post_user_id_"+id).val();
    var user_id             = $("#user_id_"+id).val();

        $.post('ajax_files/insert_comment.php',
```

{comment_des:comment_des,user_id:user_id,fk_post_id:fk_post_id,post_user_id:post_user_id},
            function(data) 
            {
                $("#ajaxdata").html(data);

```
            });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send less data to begin with maybe gzip it.

But AJAX isn't designed to be realtime. if you want realtime you should move to websockets.